# InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql, ado.net

I receive no errors when i compile the program, however as soon as I click the save button
I receive 'InvalidOperationException was unhandled'. *cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();* Is then highlighted, ive spent a while on this and no luck. Hope you can help.

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=" ";user="";password=""; database="" ;");
    con.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Staff (username, password, FirstName, SecondName, Phone, Email, Role, Phone 2, Fax)" + "values" + "("+username+","+password+","+Fname+","+Lname+","+Phone+","+email+","+role+","+Phone2+","+Fax+")");
    cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();            

    MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
    con.Close();          
}
```

Comment: How does your `MySqlCommand` object know about the `MySqlConnection` ;)?

Comment: Use Parameters in your query, it will save you from sql injections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign the connection to your command before executing it:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

And remove the call to `BeginExecuteNonQuery`. It starts an async execution and directly after that you start a synchronous one. The way your code is structured, you wanted to use the synchronous way.

Comment: All working...apart from the System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text before every entry!! But it inserts so many thanks.

Comment: @Joe Bell: if the variables you use in the query are your textboxes, change your query to use `<variable>.Text`, e.g. `username.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

Define the connection for command by

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Moreover your query seems to be incorrect.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Staff (username, password, FirstName, SecondName, Phone, Email, Role, Phone 2, Fax)"
            +"values" +"('"+username+"','"+password+"','"+Fname+"','"+Lname+"','"+Phone+"','"+email+"','"+role+"','"+Phone2+"','"+Fax+"')");
```

One more thing you have to do is rename the column name "Phone 2", do not use space in column name.

Comment: All working...apart from the System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text before every entry!! But it inserts so many thanks.